# How to attach windows to another window in DHTMLX?

Tags: dhtmlx

I'm trying to attach a window to another window using DHTMLX. how do i do that? I have created two windows and these two windows should sit inside a frame so that when I drag resize that frame, these two windows will be resized.

Answer (score 0):

The technique is the same as here: http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxLayout/samples/07_advanced/01_attach_windows_to_cell.html though the parent is a cell in a window.